# Send multiple components with a singe props in React.js with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

Is it any way I can send multiple `<MenuItem>` in one props using Material UI?

Form.js

```
export default function MyForm = (props) => {

<FormControl
        <Select value={ItemValue} >
          items={props.items}
        </Select>
</FormControl>

}
```

I have tried to output the props in a difference ways. Setting comma betweens `<MenuItem>` does only render the last `<MenuItem>`. Wrapping it with `<React.Fragment>` does work, but then the  `MenuItem value` doesn't get picket up from `value={ItemValue}`

`{ItemValue}` here is just a function that pick up the `MenuItem value` on a event handling.

App.js

```
<MyForm
    items={
           <MenuItem value={1}>value 1</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem value={2}>value 2</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem value={3}>value 3</MenuItem>
           <MenuItem value={4}>value 4</MenuItem>
          }
/>
```

Is it any  proper way to configure this?

Comment: The [Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/select/) state that the menu items must be direct descendants of the Select, which is why you would be getting the issue with the value. I would consider just providing an array of label / value  in your App.js and then mapping them out as MenuItem in your Form.js, this would allow you to specify values and labels while also keeping the MenuItems as direct descendants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Easiest** way to work this out is to pass the values as props into the *MyForm* as array of values, here is an illustrative example:
**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
const myItemsValues = [1, 2, 3, 4];
return (
    <div>
        <MyForm items={myItemsValues} />
    </div>
);}
```

**MyForm.js**

```
export default function MyForm({ items }) {
return (
    <div>
        <FormControl>
            <Select value={1}>
                {items.map((value) => {
                    return <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>;
                })}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    </div>
);}
```

### If You Insist Of Passing Them As A Collection:

```
export default function App() {
const myItemsValues = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const myItemsComponents = myItemsValues.map((value) => {
    return <MenuItem value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>;
});
return (
    <div>
        <MyForm items={myItemsComponents} />
    </div>
);}
export default function MyForm({ items }) {
return (
    <div>
        <FormControl>
            <Select value={1}>{items}</Select>
        </FormControl>
    </div>
);}
```

it's basically the same,both will produce the same results.

Comment: The actually project its more complex than the example, I have many difference forms with difference value and number of MenuItem's, but I guess I could use your solutions to figure out a way to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: You can simply manage all of them using state,but you get the main point

Comment: Don't forget to add key while mapping array of components. 

```const myItemsComponents = myItemsValues.map((value, index) => (<MenuItem key={value.id || index} value={value}>{value}</MenuItem>);```